# Save state of iOS application in AppDelegate or Uipageviewcontroller?

Tags: swift

I am using UIPageViewController for a weather app I am building. When a user leaves my app, I save his/her current page in UIPageViewController as an integer. When the user logs back into my application, should I initialize current page in AppDelegate or in UIPageViewController?

I also save user’s list of current cities as latitude and longitude locally and refetch data from a web service. I just need some advice for developing my application.

Comment: This is really depends on complexity of your app. If you just want to save/restore a bunch of integers - it doesn't really matter, you can load it  in AppDelegate or in UIPageViewController, as you wish. For more complex case you can separate model interactions to some DataSource layer and start initialisation on app launch, so when its is time to show something on UIPageViewController, your data will be ready.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. i get your answer.

Comment: How do I become smart as u?

Comment: Lol, just keep developing apps and learning new staff :)